# How to calcualte the average xcor of each agentset in a list in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo, agentset

I'm creating clusters of agents using the nw extension weak-component-clusters.
It produces a list of agentsets.

My first goal is to calculate the average xcor and ycor of each of those agentsets in the list.
I can use map to `count` the number of agents in each agentset, but I can't `map mean [xcor]`

Example:

```
clear-all
create-turtles 5
ask turtle 0 [ create-link-with turtle 1 ]
ask turtle 0 [ create-link-with turtle 2 ]
ask turtle 3 [ create-link-with turtle 4 ]

let clusters nw:weak-component-clusters ; create list of agentsets
; output: [(agentset, 2 turtles) (agentset, 3 turtles)]

map count clusters ; Works
;output: [2 3]

map mean [xcor] clusters ; Does not work
;output: Expected a literal value
```

Secondary question: I will be calculating the distance between the clusters next and I was wondering if there was an extension or function that I could use instead of just using the distance between two points formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the usage of your `map` function. As long as you are doing a very simple calculation (like for example your counting) `map function list` is sufficient. But when you want to calculate your `mean xcor`, you will need to add some [anonymous procedure](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#arrow) syntax.

```
map [ list-item -> function list-item ] list
```

In this case, you define a variable name that will be used for all the items of the list. This variable name is on the left of the `->`. On the right side of the `->`, you add a function utilising that variable. This function will then be applied to every item of the initial list, as you already know from `map`.

In your case, that gives us:

```
map [a-cluster -> mean [xcor] of a-cluster] clusters
```

Standard netlogo has a function for calculating the distance between agents (`distance`) and the distance between an agent and a point (`distancexy`) but no function for a distance between points. That said, the mathematical formula is simple so you could easily write your own function for that using `to-report`